# How to get the sum of the added cell

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help for getting the sum total of all the prices value in the 3rd column w/c is added by a button here is my code:

```js
var i = 0;
var ii = 0;
var iii = 0;
var iiii = 0;

function buttonClick1() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById("qty1").value = i;
}

function decreClick1() {
  if (i <= 0)
    return;
  i--;
  document.getElementById("qty1").value = i;
}

function buttonClick2() {
  ii++;
  document.getElementById("qty2").value = ii;
}

function decreClick2() {
  if (ii <= 0)
    return;
  ii--;
  document.getElementById("qty2").value = ii;
}

function buttonClick3() {
  iii++;
  document.getElementById("qty3").value = iii;
}

function decreClick3() {
  if (iii <= 0)
    return;
  iii--;
  document.getElementById("qty3").value = iii;
}

function buttonClick4() {
  iiii++;
  document.getElementById("qty4").value = iiii;
}

function decreClick4() {
  if (iiii <= 0)
    return;
  iiii--;
  document.getElementById("qty4").value = iiii;
}

var price1 = 14;
var price2 = 24;
var price3 = 34;
var price4 = 44;
var item1 = "apple";
var item2 = "boy";
var item3 = "cat";
var item4 = "dog";

function a() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cel1.innerHTML = item1;
  cel2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
  cel3.innerHTML = "PHP" + price1 * i;


}

function b() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cel1.innerHTML = item2;
  cel2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
  cel3.innerHTML = "PHP" + price2 * ii;
}

function c() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cel1.innerHTML = item3;
  cel2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("qty3").value;
  cel3.innerHTML = "PHP" + price3 * iii;
}

function d() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow(1);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cel1.innerHTML = item4;
  cel2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("qty4").value;
  cel3.innerHTML = "PHP" + price4 * iiii;
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Apple</p>
<p>PHP<s> 24 </s> PHP 14</p>
<button type="button" onclick="decreClick1()">-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" id="qty1" />
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick1()">+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="a()">Add to cart</button>

<p>Boy</p>
<p>PHP<s> 34 </s> PHP 24</p>
<button type="button" onclick="decreClick2()">-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" id="qty2" />
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick2()">+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="b()">Add to cart</button>

<p>Cat</p>
<p>PHP<s> 44 </s> PHP 34</p>
<button type="button" onclick="decreClick3()">-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" id="qty3" />
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick3()">+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="c()">Add to cart</button>


<p>Dog</p>
<p>PHP<s> 54 </s> PHP 44</p>
<button type="button" onclick="decreClick4()">-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" id="qty4" />
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick4()">+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="d()">Add to cart</button>


<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption><b>Cart List:<b></caption>
  <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><b>Total:</b></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The thing here is when I put a quantity and click the button it goes to the table but I can't get the sum of all the prices. I need the correct function to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's always better to get your example working on a site like "Codepen" or jsFiddle, that way people can see what you're talking about.

One thing you could do is, when you add the price to the list here: `cel3.innerHTML = "PHP"+price1*i;`

also have a global variable called "total" or something, and every time you add an item to the list, also add the price to "total" (before adding the string "PHP")  then just assign total as the innerText of the `<td><b>Total:</b></td>` line.

Hope that's clear, otherwise just ask and I'll try to explain more!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that the value of an input is a string. so you need to write `cel3.innerHTML = "PHP"+(price*parseInt(qty.value))`

Next comes my code. I tried to reduce your code in as much as posible because it's extremely verbose. I hope you won't mind.

```js
let items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_wrap"));
let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

items.map((item) =>{
  let qty = item.querySelector(".qty");
  let price = item.querySelector(".price").innerHTML;
  let name = item.querySelector(".name").innerHTML;
  let plus = item.querySelector(".plus");
  let minus = item.querySelector(".minus");
  let add2cart = item.querySelector(".add2cart");
  
  plus.addEventListener("click", ()=>upClick(qty));
  minus.addEventListener("click", ()=>decreClick(qty));
  add2cart.addEventListener("click", ()=>add(name,price,qty));
})




function upClick(qty) {
        let i = qty.value;
        i++
        qty.value = i;
    }

    function decreClick(qty){
        let i = qty.value;  
        if(i == 0)return;
        i--;
        qty.value = i; 
    }


function add(name,price,qty){
if(qty.value > 0){  
let newRow = table.insertRow(1);
let cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
let cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
let cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
cel1.innerHTML = name;
cel2.innerHTML = qty.value;
cel3.innerHTML = "PHP"+(price*parseInt(qty.value));
}
}
```

```css
input{
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

table{margin-top:5em;}
```

```html
<article class="item_wrap">
<p class="name">Apple</p>
<p>PHP<s> 24 </s> PHP <span class="price">14</span></p>
<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" class="qty" />
<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="add2cart" >Add to cart</button>
</article>

<article class="item_wrap">
<p class="name">Boy</p>
<p>PHP<s> 34 </s> PHP <span class="price">24</span></p>
<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" class="qty" />
<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="add2cart" >Add to cart</button>
</article>



<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption><b>Cart List:</b></caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><b>Total:</b></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: getting the total for the cart:

```js
let items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_wrap"));
let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
let prices = [];



items.map((item) =>{
  let qty = item.querySelector(".qty");
  let price = item.querySelector(".price").innerHTML;
  let name = item.querySelector(".name").innerHTML;
  let plus = item.querySelector(".plus");
  let minus = item.querySelector(".minus");
  let add2cart = item.querySelector(".add2cart");
  
  plus.addEventListener("click", ()=>upClick(qty));
  minus.addEventListener("click", ()=>decreClick(qty));
  add2cart.addEventListener("click", ()=>add(name,price,qty));
})




function upClick(qty) {
        let i = qty.value;
        i++
        qty.value = i;
    }

    function decreClick(qty){
        let i = qty.value;  
        if(i == 0)return;
        i--;
        qty.value = i; 
    }




function add(name,price,qty){
if(qty.value > 0){  
let newRow = table.insertRow(1);
let cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
let cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
let cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
cel1.innerHTML = name;
cel2.innerHTML = qty.value;
let _price = price*parseInt(qty.value);
cel3.innerHTML = "PHP"+_price;
  
prices.push(_price);
}
  sum();
}


function sum(){
  let totalAmount = 0;
  prices.map((p) =>{
    totalAmount += p;
  });
  theTotal.innerHTML = totalAmount;
}
```

```css
input{
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

table{margin-top:5em;}
```

```html
<article class="item_wrap">
<p class="name">Apple</p>
<p>PHP<s> 24 </s> PHP <span class="price">14</span></p>
<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" class="qty" />
<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="add2cart" >Add to cart</button>
</article>

<article class="item_wrap">
<p class="name">Boy</p>
<p>PHP<s> 34 </s> PHP <span class="price">24</span></p>
<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="0" class="qty" />
<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="add2cart" >Add to cart</button>
</article>



<table style="width:50%" border="1">
  <caption><b>Cart List:<b></caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><b>Total:</b></td>
    <td id="theTotal">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the help right now i have trouble finding how i will add all the values from the price column, i mean all the cel3 values. Once i click the add to cart button it will show the total price times the quantity you input but it doesn't show in the '<td><b>Total:</b></td>' all the sum of the added prices ... i try to add all the cell values but it replaces with another cel3 values using this 'document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = (price*parseInt(qty.value));

Comment: I've posted an update. Please take a look to see if this is what you need

Comment: thanks sir much appreciated i'll try to understand your code and see if i can modify it .

Comment: I forgot to tell you: in this moment, if you add an other `<article class="item_wrap">` with the same structure, just changing the name and the price, it would work as expected.